# Robust DateTime parser library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, time, date

There is a great need for a Robust DateTime parser library for .NET, prefer C#
DateTime.TryParse supports very few formats
I know the question has been asked a year ago but with no good answer.
There must be good libs out there! Commercial or open source

I looked at [noda-time](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/).
But blog says it does not do parsing yet

Dates fall into two categories:

Date formats:   All the various date formats

- 2011-09-09T20:00:00
- 29 September 2011
- 6 September 2011  7:00pm
- 1/1/2009, 12:00PM

Natural Dates:  How a Human would say/write it

- Today
- Tomorrrow
- Mondays, 6PM
- Every Monday, 6PM
- Every Friday
- First Monday of every month
- Last Sunday of the month
- Everyday
- 1st of the Month

Comment: I think you either need to wait for Noda Time (parsing is being worked on), or do it yourself. If you contribute to Noda Time you could speed things up...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [C# Date Time Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/date_time_parser_cs.aspx) of Sergey Stoyan.

Comment: Sergey's parser works great. Recommended.All that hassle converted into: `if (DateTimeRoutines.TryParseDate(RawDate, DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat.UK_DATE, out parsedDate))`

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I was looking for, other than it orders them by "most likely" datetime format, rather than "first", but it's open source, so easy enough to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for but I like [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method.

Comment: doesn't TryParseExact force you to provide a format yourself? I think the OP wants a library that will do the parsing for you a la DateTime.TryParse but with more features. But yes, you could whip up a parse method using TryParseExact that would cover the cases asked above.

Comment: @arviman: There is an overload of `TryParseExact` which takes a collection of formats. But inbuilt BCL date time suport will not do "natural dates" as specified by the Q.

Comment: The date is comming from a web site or user input and the format is unknown.  Parsing a known format is easy detecting and parsing unknown format is very hard.