# How can I convert date values from the multiple different types that are string to datetime with one method?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have multiple datetime values. I would like to convert them to datetime with one method.

The date values may change by system regional settings like below.

```
'7/26/2013 12:00:00 AM'
'26.7.2013 12:00:00'
'07-26-2013 12:00 AM'
```

Is there a way to do this without changing system regional settings with **one method**?

Comment: [DateTime.TryParse(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) ? as per the doc's `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse the string representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture.`

Comment: I have tried DateTime.TryParse, but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime.TryParse all possible type of dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326127/datetime-tryparse-all-possible-type-of-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question [DateTime.TryParse all possible type of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326127/datetime-tryparse-all-possible-type-of-dates) may be of some use to you.

Here is the snippet:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sl-SI");
string[] fmts = ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, fmts, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt))
{
    DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    Check = true;
}
```

**Update:**

This codeproject article may also be of use to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33298/C-Date-Time-Parser

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont know culture info. That may change. Should I use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ?

Comment: I would use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, for most cases that should work just fine.  http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/  Also provides a list of culture names in case you need em